# Can Richfaces components be inserted into rich:editor component?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I have another Richfaces question which may seem rather weird.  I am developing a web-based application, using Richfaces for a front-end, that allows users to create templates for certain documents.  For example: the user is presented with a rich:editor component, which, perhaps, has certain text already typed in, but it also has an input for a date, or specific text.  The date can be entered in rich:calendar, the text can be entered in rich:inplaceInput, but the main idea is to be able to place those components INSIDE the rich:editor.  I was trying to find an example where it's used and couldn't.  So, my question is: is it even possible?  Can you place RichFaces components (and, maybe, Seam components) into rich:editor?  If not, is there a something similar out there that allows the user to do this?  Can Seam do that?  The reason I'm asking about Seam is because it appears to have some template-friendly logic and can work along with JSF and Richfaces.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially your asking if you can add HTML elements to a textarea tag, and have them work.  Unfortunately, no you can't.

What I've done in the past for such things has been to either weave boilerplate text, with inplaceInput, and free form text areas, or to simply provide the needed fields above/beside/below the editor.

Comment: Thanks, that's kinda what I thought, unfortunately.  I was able to have a workaround: switching from rich:panel (where you update input values) to rich:editor (where you only update text, inputs are replaced by <span> tags as placeholders).